# why does my directive cant set init value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Why does AngularJS include an empty option in select? and my default value is empty ?
blow is my code:

```
.directive('gettheme',function( ){
  return {
    restrict:"AE",
    template:"<select ng-init='themedata=theme[0]' ng-model='themedata' ng-options='item for item in theme' class='form-control'></select>",
    link:function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.theme=['macarons', 'infographic'];
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`ng-init` invoked before `link` function, so try this solution:

```
.directive('gettheme',function(){
return {
    restrict:"AE",
    template:"<select ng-init='themedata=theme[0]' ng-model='themedata' ng-options='item for item in theme' class='form-control'></select>",
    link:{
       pre:function(scope, element, attrs){
              scope.theme=['macarons', 'infographic'];
           }
    }
}})
```

or this one:

```
.directive('gettheme',function( ){
  return {
    controller:function($scope){
      $scope.theme=['macarons', 'infographic'];
    },
    restrict:"AE",
    template:"<select ng-init='themedata=theme[0]' ng-model='themedata' ng-options='item for item in theme' class='form-control'></select>",
  }
})
```

or this:

```
.directive('gettheme',function(){
    return {
        restrict:"AE",
        template:"<select ng-model='themedata' ng-options='item for item in theme' class='form-control'></select>",
        link:function(scope, element, attrs){
          scope.theme=['macarons', 'infographic'];
          scope.themedata=scope.theme[0];
        }
    }})
```